# No desktop after installing Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

I decided to install ElementaryOs dist on my laptop (dual boot with W10) and, after trying and trying I cant figure out what am I doing wrong or whats the problem. 
I made the correct and typical partitions (root home swap boot) and after finishing the installation, when I click restart now, the screen gets Frozen and nothing happens. I restart it by the power off button because it doesn't even goes to the terminal or anything and when I start the system with ElementaryOs, I log in and the desktop doesn't load, I can move the mouse and that but I can only see the wallpaper. I tried everything I found on the web and nothing worked. I tried also to install other Linux distributions and Ubuntu doesn't work either, it doesn't pass from the Ubuntu loading screen or it gets purple or black. I think the problem may be the graphic card (drivers maybe?).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that has been addressed a number of times. Usually the fix is to run the below command in the terminal:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: I recommend reinstalling the pantheon desktop.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work either, I think it's about the graphic card drivers or kernel. Any Linux dist works at all so i have no idea